# Do I still need low-resolution images for using Interface Builder when developing iPhone app for iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, interface-builder

I started to develop an iPhone app for iOS 7.

Since iOS 7 does not support devices with non-retina display for the iPhone/iPod touch, and it  uses high-resolution images on non-retina iPads (iPad 2 and iPad mini) in the iPhone emulation mode, now I think we don't need to provide low-resolution images when developing an iPhone-only app which deployment target is iOS 7.

I thought it's great, but soon I faced a problem when I used a Storyboard; apparently Interface Builder can not display high-resolution images which file names end with @2x.

I feel it's really pity that we have to provide the low-resolution images ONLY for the Interface Builder...

Is there any good workaround for this? Or do we still have to provide low-resolution images if we want to use the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that an iOS 7 iPhone-only app is not going to run on any single-resolution devices, so you only need to provide double-resolution images. Do what you have always done in the past: refer to your image as `myImage` but name the actual image file `myImage@2x.png`. Even better, use the asset catalog! Place the double-resolution image in the `2x` slot and refer to it by the name of that image set. Either way, this will work perfectly both in the storyboard editor and in the running app; in the storyboard editor, the Media Library and things like buttons that have images will display your image's name as `myImage`.

Comment: So, does this mean the non-retina iPad mini uses @2x images when running iPhone apps?

Comment: I don't know; I don't have one. But I did what I just described in my iPhone-only apps when I adapted them for iOS 7 and my apps were not rejected and look fine on my devices. You'll notice that the asset catalog doesn't even have a `1x` image slot for an iPhone-only iOS 7-only app, so what I've just described must be legal and correct.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the answer! Asset catalog sure did solve my problem! In fact I tried it once, but the Interface Builder didn't display the image because I was setting the image name "myImage.png" or "myImage@2x.png". I could see the image if I removed the ".png" and referred to it by the image set name "myImage" as you have described.

Comment: Jesse, I have a non-retina iPad mini running iOS 7 and confirmed that it always uses @2x images when I run an iPhone-only app. (It doesn't show x2 zooming button.)

Comment: @JesseRusak there is no non-retina iPad that can run iOS 7!

Comment: @powtac iPad 2 and nonretina iPad mini can run iOS 7 very happily

Comment: @matt interesting! I was researching on this topic but mainly for iPhone only. And I thought this is the case for iPad as well! Thanks!

Comment: @powtac Yup, you were exactly right if you'd said iPhone. But iPad is not the same thing.

Comment: How has it taken me this long to realise this :D This is awesome!