# Is iPhone SE download only 2x icons from iPA?

Tags: ios, iphone

As we are providing `1x, 2x, & 3x` icons in the assets.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

QW 1). As in above link iPhone SE uses `2x` image, is that mean when iPhone SE user download app from the appstore then only `2x` will be downloaded ? (`1x & 3x` discarded)

Qw 2). As i mentioned above link i haven't found any of iPhone using `1x`. then why Apple uses that ?

Comment: @mag_zbc as latest xcode 10.2 only supports `ios 8+` & iPhone 3GS uses `ios6(last supported version)` means no use of `1x` ?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602328/341994

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Swift or iTunes Connect so please stop adding irrelevant tags

Comment: @matt can you explain more ?

Comment: I think user which have jailbroken device they probably extract from ipa & check.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer of #1**: App has different app store file size for every device, as per your device app download from apple store.

See this example

[image]

**Answer of #2**: If your app is not iPhone-specific (that is, it can be run on iPad, either natively or in compatibility mode), be aware that iPad 2 is not Retina-class, and can run iOS 7 and iOS 8, and defaults to loading 1x icons if available.

See this post for more info: [Is there a requirement to supply @1x images as well as @2x for successful iOS submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180942/is-there-a-requirement-to-supply-1x-images-as-well-as-2x-for-successful-ios-su)

Comment: So whats the answer for Qw 1?

Comment: from where you got this image & info >?

Comment: @Amit you can see you app file sizes from iTunes account.

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1 : Yes, from IPA only 2x images downloaded for iPhone SE.

Ans 2 : When we are uploading our app in Appstore we have no idea by which device apple's QA team check our app. If they would check our app with "iPad Mini 1" or any other 1x scale factor device. Then 1x image is necessary.